# Dynamically making column and rows as hyperlinks in Vaadin setting properties also

Tags: java, vaadin

I am new to Vaadin. I am using a Vaadin table and getting the table data from a database table. So one of the columns data I want to make it as hyperlink.

I am doing something like this

```
  table.addContainerProperty("First Name", Component.class,  null);
    table.addContainerProperty("Last Name",  String.class,  null);
    table.addContainerProperty("Year",       Integer.class, null);
```

I saw example where I can mention column type as hyperlink. Assuming if I give column type as hyperlink, how can I add hyperlink properties to the row values.

If those values are static I can do it, but they are coming from database and I just bind them.

Answer (score 2):

You could add generated column to the table and return a link for each table row.

Example:

Assuming there's a property "LinkUrl" in the table's data source holding link's URL.

```
table.addGeneratedColumn("WebsiteLink", new ColumnGenerator() {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public Object generateCell(Table source, Object itemId, Object columnId) {

        String linkUrl = (String) source.getItem(itemId).getItemProperty("LinkUrl").getValue();
        Link websiteLink = new Link(linkUrl, new ExternalResource(linkUrl));
        websiteLink.setTargetName("_blank");
        return websiteLink;
    }
});
```

Edit: or if you are adding items directly to the table, you could add container property with the type `Link` and return a link for each `Item`.